# Chrome Developer Tools hangs when inspecting big object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Developer tools hangs when I debug some JS object with for example 100K elements, just passing the mouse over the element is enough to hang the debugger for more than 10 seconds (the same if I try to print in with console.log).

Is this normal? because I couldn't anything related here or Google.

Comment: Sure, thats a lot of data to process.

Comment: then is a really bad design, it should not process all that on mouse over at least